# Migration from IPV4 to IPV6 in C codes

Tags: c, networking, ip, ipv6

I want to adapt my old C codebases, that were written for IPv4, to work with IPv6.  What do I need to change so that my C code works with both IPv4 and IPv6?

Comment: What library are you using for networking?

Comment: Question is too vague. Entire books have been written about this. It's not simply a matter of changing some API calls.

Comment: +1 to compensate for downvoters. This question is not deep or vague. It has a simple and direct answer that may entail a good deal of work, depending on the size of the codebase, but it's not worthy of "entire books".

Comment: For what it's worth, the question is not very well-written or otherwise worthy of +1, but it also doesn't deserve to be closed.

Comment: I also think this is a very valid question, so voting to reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find all code that uses `inet_aton`, `inet_ntoa`, `gethostbyname`, `gethostbyaddr`, `htonl`, `htons`, `ntohl`, `ntohs`, and any direct `sockaddr_in` manipulation and replace it with simple calls to `getaddrinfo` or `getnameinfo`. This will make your code much simpler and more maintainable and IPv6 will automatically work with no additional effort.

Comment: +1 Exactly what Stevens said in Unix Network Programming.

Comment: You may need to change where you make your `socket()` call(s), since it should use the values returned by `getaddrinfo()` rather than hardcoded address family and protocol numbers.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point too.

Comment: You're assuming his application doesn't do a lot with sockets. I see nothing about broadcasting, protocol constants, ioctl calls that may not work with IPv6 like SIOCGIFCONF, etc. It may be the case that it's relevant for this question, but we don't know. Hence, it's vague.

Comment: Non-system-configuration apps have no business inspecting or poking at interfaces. I'm assuming his app is just moderately sane.

Comment: Even for regular applications there is more too it than just dealing with larger binary addresses. Examples include dealing with the complexities of listening on both v6 and v4 and dealing with working through a set of IPs in sequence because you aren't gauranteed to have both v4 and v6 connectivity.